# Cannot connect to internet with VMware running on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, vmware

My OS is Windows 7. I installed VMware version 7. I am running Mac OS X virtually. But I am not able to access to internet. I am using wireless internet in my host box (Windows 7).

I also tried the bridged mode, but it's also not working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked for port availability within VMware VSwitch?

Comment: where to check that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching to bridged networking mode.  When just trying to let a VM access the Internet, I've found it's easiest to use bridged networking so it appears as another networked computer.

Comment: Hi.. I tried that too. Its not working.

Comment: Perhaps try giving the VM a static IP address, at least for testing?

Comment: How to and where to give it ?

Comment: Set it to bridged networking.  Check your IP address on Windows by opening command prompt and typing "ipconfig", then in Mac OS X change "Configure" to "Manually", and type in another IP address with the same first three numbers (if your Windows machine is 192.168.1.102, try using 192.168.1.202 for Mac OS X). Use the same subnet mask and gateway address that the Windows machine has.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and, after making sure all of the settings were correct and still not being able to connect, I just restarted my virtual machine and it was fixed. Simple, but worth a try!